# Error in POST request (Java EE)

Tags: java, php, tomcat, jakarta-ee, vk

I work with Vkontakte callback api and I write bot in Java using tomcat.

In callback api doc exist sample on php:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

So data reply in POST format.

**In my server POST request exist, but request is empty**

This is my Java code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,
IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
    String type = (String) req.getParameterMap().toString();

    if (type != null) {
        switch (type) {
        case "confirmation":
            pw.print(confirm_token);
            break;
        default:
            pw.print(req.getParameterMap().size());
            break;
        }
    } else {
        pw.print("error");
    }

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: improperly retrieved data from getParameterMap(), google "java map" examples. What exactly is response?

Comment: @JacekCz if I send standard POST request from browser, that server response number of my POST key-value, but if this do Vkontakte, response is 0

Comment: Your code is incomplete, what You say cannot be confirmed

Comment: NOTICE: String type is a test value, I use it only for test